# How to hard code Magento static block ids? or any other similar solutions?

Tags: magento

My client changing Magento static block ids frequently. Doing so, block contents not rendering front-end. Is there any way to overcome this issue?

Comment: Sounds like a better fit for the Magento Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

I liked your (@Chatura Dinesh Halwatura) idea to lock CMS-Blocks so i wrote a little module which does exactly what you want. I put it onto magento connect. Its called Cartware_CmsLock.

Here the link to the module:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalog/product/view/id/19176/s/cartware-cmslock-7465/?___store=mc_default_store

Comment: This module really useful for me as a Magento frontend developer. Thanks for building this.